# В заданном предложении найти наибольшее количество идущих подряд пробелов

Tags: c++, c++11

В заданном предложении найти наибольшее количество пробелов, что
расположены подряд. Исключить из данного предложения длинные
последовательности пробелов. 1 часть я уже решил , я просто не понял как решить 2-ю я знаю что мне надо использовать функцию erase .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
string s;
cout<<"Enter text: ";
getline(cin,s);
int k = 0;
int max = 0;
int str = s.length();
for(int i = 0; i< str; i++){
    if(s[i] == ' '){
        k++;
    }else{
     k = 0;
    }if(k>max){
    max = k;
    }
}
 
cout<<s.erase(max);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Непонятно - вам нужно **совсем удалить** пробелы или заменить последовательности из нескольких пробелов одним? И делать для всех последовательностей пробелов или только для самой длинной?

Comment: @Harry вообще написано "исключить", что подразумевает удалить, и да самые длинные последовательности. Я думаю если у нескольких последовательностей длинна одинакова и она максимальна, то их нужно удалить. Но код автора удаляет только самую первую длинную последовательность, так что может автор не точно изложил свой вопрос.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Видите ли, это ваша трактовка, но при всем уважении к ней я бы хотел увидеть точно сформулированное задание (а не вольный пересказ задания топикстартером :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну если я вас правильно понял, то у вас не получается удалить последовательность пробелов длинной `max`.

Строчкой:

```
s.erase(max);
```

Вы удаляете все символы начиная с индекса `max`.

А вам нужно удалить `max` символов начиная с начала последовательности.

Например при проверке:

```
if(k > max){
    max = k;
    index = i;
}
```

`index` - индекс последнего символа в самой длинной последовательности.

И далее пишите так:

```
cout << s.erase(index - max, max);
```

То есть `index - max` это индекс начала последовательности, `max` это кол-во сколько нужно удалить символов.

Поподробней про `erase` можно почитать [тут](http://cybern.ru/stringerase.html)

Пример выхода программы:

```
Enter text: Privet  mir        kak dela    ?
Privet  mi kak dela    ?
```

Comment: @YozhykovAnatolii ну конечно. Это уже вывод результата.

Comment: @YozhykovAnatolii если вам помог мой ответ, то отметьте его пожалуйста как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа :)